# Is there a function to extract a random line from a text file using Shell?

Tags: shell

Is there a commande Shell to extract at random a line from a text file ??
My file composed of for columns seperated by : 
" id : name : age : city "

Comment: Please, share your existing code, that will make us a better idea of what you want to achieve and will be easier to find a solution. See [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuf` to randomize a file and then select the first line using `-n`, e.g.

```
shuf -n 1 yourfile
```

Comment: There is little logic in pipeing to `head`, when you know that `shuf` has `-n` option.

Comment: Thanks, @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$RANDOM` modulo the number of lines in your file plus 1.

```
sed "$(expr $RANDOM % $(wc -l <file> | sed "s/^[[:space:]]*//; s/[^[:digit:]].*$//") + 1)!d" <file>
```

(Replace `<file>` with the path to your file.)

Answer (score -1):

No, the ''Shell'' has basic things which has a meaning and huge impact to other people. For small task you'll have to combine your own cmd.